# How to install miniforge3 to python 3.11.x?

Tags: python-3.x, conda, miniconda, mini-forge

I upgraded my python version to 3.11. I tried to install miniforge3.
On the website,
[miniforge3](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge3);
I can't find references to python 3.11.x.

Guide me on to install it!
I follow the instructions on the site:
[/miniforge-setup](https://kirenz.github.io/codelabs/codelabs/miniforge-setup/#0)